# WOL and Windows Update Script

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I am currently building a `powershell` script. The script needs to wake a list of computers using `WOL` and tell them to run the windows update and install the update, once the update is done it needs to shut down all computers on the list.

I have the first part of the script working. All computers from my `csv` list will `WOL`. The next part for me is to get them to update their OS.

**Question**

Here is were i'm not sure what the best way to achieve this is. The script will somehow need to know when the computer has finished its update to tell it to shut down. Is this possible in `powershell`?

**Examples**

I was thinking there are two ways I can go about this:

1. I can use a update script which runs locally on each host computer and run this script remotely from the WOL script.
2. Or I can run it all from the one script i.e. WOL all computers from list then tell them to update, wait for 1 hour then tell them all to shut down.

**Summary**

So to summarize what I was asking:

> What is the best process for a WOL, Windows Update , Shutdown Script?

1. Wake all machines remotely , then remotely run a script on each local machine to update windows and shutdown once the update is finished.
2. Wake all machines remotely, send an message to update remotely, wait around 1 hour (All updates should be finished by then) Then shutdown remotely.